# Proving theorems about implication in propositional logic

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

I am having trouble giving proofs for these theorems. I understand them intuitively but I am not sure how to explain them formally.

So for (i), if Φ, α ⊨ β then this implies that Φ ⊨ α → β because when Φ and α are true β is as well, so the formula α → β would be satisfied as both antecedent and consequent are true. If Φ ⊨ α → β then this implies that Φ,α ⊨ β because when Φ is true then so is α → β, so if Φ,α is true then α → β must still be true (since Φ is) and the only way for it to hold would be if β is also true. My problem is really in trying to formalize this into a proof by induction or some sort of more formal proof then an explanation. My best guess would be to try and prove it as a universal conditional regarding truth valuations?

(i) For any set Φ of formulas and any two formulas α and β, prove that Φ, α ⊨ β iff Φ ⊨ α → β.

(ii) Prove that {α1, α2, ... , αk} ⊨ β iff  ⊨ α1 → α2 → ... → αk → β.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: In (ii) it should be $\alpha_1\to(\alpha_2\to(...(\alpha_k\to \beta)...))$. This follows from (i) by induction on $k$. Take $\Phi=\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{k-1}\}$.

Comment: Show how you have tried to explain them so we can see what trouble you are having.  What is the intuition you have for them?

Comment: Ok, I am sorry about that.

So for (i), if  Φ, α ⊨ β then this implies that Φ ⊨ α → β because when Φ and α are true β is as well, so the formula α → β would be satisfied as both antecedent and consequent are true. If Φ ⊨ α → β then this implies that Φ,α  ⊨ β because when Φ is true then so is α → β, so if Φ,α is true then α → β must still be true (since Φ is) and the only way for it to hold would be if β is also true. My problem is really in trying to formalize this into a proof by induction or some sort of more formal proof then an explanation.

Comment: (ii) would then follow from (i) as pointed out in the first comment

Comment: Well, other than that $Φ$ is a set of propositions rather than a single proposition, that is okay.

Comment: Yes my mistake, thanks!